# ArgumentException when deserializing using JSON.Net

Tags: windows-phone-7, json.net

I have an object as follows,

```
public class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<double?>> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I serialize using, `string myJson = JsonConvert.Serialize(myFoo)` and get sensible Json. However when I run `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Foo>(myJson)` I get an ArgumentException `Parameter name: value`.

Why is this?

I am using Json.Net on a Windows Phone 7.1 project.

Edit: Here is an example object and the Json it produces,

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo()
        {
            Bar = new Dictionary<string,List<double?>>() {
                {"Flim", new List<double?>() { 0, 0.2, null, 0.9 }},
                {"Flam", new List<double?>() { 0.0,0.1, null, null}},
            }
        };
```

The contents of myJson after serialization (double quote escapes removed)

```
{"Bar":{"Flim":[0.0,0.2,null,0.9],"Flam":[0.0,0.1,null,null]}}
```

Comment: Please show the JSON you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: Making the `List<double?>` non-nullable works i.e. `List<double>` - it looks like the nulls are causing the problem. Unfortunately I need this to be nullable ...

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me using Json.Net 4.5.11 on .NET 4.5 in standard Windows.  Here is the program I used (below).  Can you try running this exact code in your environment and see if it works?  If so, then your ArgumentException must be coming from somewhere else.  If not, then that seems to point to a difference between Windows and Windows Phone environments.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo myFoo = new Foo()
        {
            Bar = new Dictionary<string, List<double?>>() 
            {
                { "Flim", new List<double?>() { 0, 0.2, null, 0.9 } },
                { "Flam", new List<double?>() { 0.0, 0.1, null, null } },
            }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFoo);

        Console.WriteLine(json);

        Foo foo2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<double?>> kvp in foo2.Bar)
        {
            Console.Write(kvp.Key);
            Console.Write(":");
            string sep = " {";
            foreach (double? d in kvp.Value)
            {
                Console.Write(sep);
                Console.Write(d.HasValue ? d.Value.ToString() : "null");
                sep = ", ";
            }
            Console.WriteLine("}");
        }

    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<double?>> Bar { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{"Bar":{"Flim":[0.0,0.2,null,0.9],"Flam":[0.0,0.1,null,null]}}
Flim: {0, 0.2, null, 0.9}
Flam: {0, 0.1, null, null}
```

Comment: I created a brand new project and included the latest JSON (5.0.5) available via NuGet. I copied the code into a button callback. `Console.WriteLine` lines were commented out since they do not do anything AFAIK in a Windows Phone project. I got the same argument exception - this is either due to a difference in JSON.Net versions or the Windows Phone environment ...

Comment: I am unfortunately not a Windows Phone guru.  I downloaded the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK and attempted to set up a "Hello World" app so that I could try to reproduce the problem in the same environment as you, but I am having trouble just getting a simple button click to work in my test project!  I will try to play with it more when I have some more time, perhaps over the weekend.